# Any way to open CSV file with PHP and replace certain text?

Tags: php, file, csv

As the title says, I am trying to open a CSV file that is comma delimited and I need to update specific part of the CSV string.  Is that possible?  I have looked into fseek but that only let's me count the number of bytes from the BOF so that won't work as each CSV would be different.

I was thinking if it was possible if I set the specific part I want to change with something like "CHANGEME" and have PHP look for that string/character and replace that with whatever I need.

Possible?

Comment: what is your goal, can't you just treat it as regular text file?

Comment: csv file gets created at stage 1 but at stage 2 there is a certain data that needs to go into the csv...and no I can't just create the csv after stage 2

Answer (score 1):

Try [`fgetcsv` (documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)) or `str_getcsv`.

Maybe these functions will help.